# Create dynamic array of arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, xml, .net-3.5

In C# I am trying to create a array of arrays or it can be called as jagged array using XML data.  But I am totally confused how to start

XML Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MAIN>
  <Items>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Data>data1</Data>
    <Category>category1</Category>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Data>data2</Data>
    <Category>category2</Category>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Name>name3</Name>
    <Data>data3</Data>
    <Category>category2</Category>//same category as above
  </Items>
  ...
  ...
  <Items>
    <Name>name20</Name>
    <Data>data20</Data>
    <Category>category16</Category>
  </Items>
</MAIN>
```

Now I need to create an array with category1, category2, ... upto what the categories is there on Category Node, need to create a separate arrays of each category to store the item name and data so I can retrieve them for my use.

From above sample xml I need the same category items in a single array

Items and Category count is fully dynamic. 
How to do this dynamically?

Comment: Have a look at serialization in C#, that should point you in the right direction

Comment: I am very new to programming expecting help on it

Comment: You can at least try it yourself and then edit your question with the problems you encounter. The internet is full of examples how to do what you are asking! Search for https://www.google.com/search?q=xml+deserialization+c%23

Comment: Thanks for reply i am totally new to programming so i unable to understand those things how to spell for internet search

Comment: How could you ever improve your skills if not by trying (and failing) by yourself?

Comment: @Uwe Keim i tried some but i am not getting the perfect thing so i asked here

Comment: Start by forgetting about arrays. You need a List, and probably a `class Item`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is it possible to create dynamic list names

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with linq

```
var categorized = xe.Descendants("Items")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Element("Category").Value)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Category = x.Key,
        Items = x.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

You will add `Items` with same `Category` element in to a group.
Then you will select `Category` and `Items` in the group.
It will returns `List<{Category, List<Items>}>` for you

This is what categorized structure looks like

```
[
  {
    "Category": "category1",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Items": {
          "Name": "name1",
          "Data": "data1",
          "Category": "category1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "category2",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Items": {
          "Name": "name2",
          "Data": "data2",
          "Category": "category2"
        }
      },
      {
        "Items": {
          "Name": "name3",
          "Data": "data3",
          "Category": "category2",
          "#text": "//same category as above\n  "
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "category16",
    "Items": [
      {
        "Items": {
          "Name": "name20",
          "Data": "data20",
          "Category": "category16"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: how to create dynamic array names need some sample code so that it can help me

Comment: What is dynamic array names?

Comment: category will be the dynamic it can be any name or any count

Comment: You mean `Category` as an element name or `Category` element value?

Comment: it is the value i am saying category1,category2

Comment: i mean if want to access the array data like array[0][0] it should show name1 it means category1 and category2 should order by ascending how can i do that small code is really helpful